# How to Fix `Flutter LateInitializationError: Field 'fieldname' has not been initialized` error in 2023?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch users coordinates with geolocator package. I've implemented a late initializer for coordinates type and assign value in initState. but whenever I use the `late` keyword it throws an error. but I assign a string for lat and long with `late` keyword, and it works fine.

```
  late String lat;
  late String long;
  late Coordinates coordinates;

   Future<Position> getCurrentLocation() async {
    bool serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error("not enabled");
    }

    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error("permission denied");
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error("ever denied");
    }

    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    getCurrentLocation().then((value) async {
      lat = "${value.latitude}";
      long = "${value.longitude}";

      List<Placemark> placemarks =
          await placemarkFromCoordinates(value.latitude, value.longitude);

      Placemark place = placemarks[0];

      String currentLocation = "${place.locality}, ${place.country}";

      final location = tz.getLocation(currentLocation);
      DateTime date = tz.TZDateTime.from(DateTime.now(), location);
      CalculationParameters params = CalculationMethod.MuslimWorldLeague();
      coordinates = Coordinates(value.latitude, value.longitude);

      setState(() {});
    });
  }
```

when I use lat or long in a text widget it displays the coordinates. but when I try to use `coordinates.latitude` it throws `Flutter LateInitializationError: Field 'fieldname' has not been initialized` error. it does the same thing when I try to assign a late initializer with such types. how can I fix this kind of problem?

Comment: The variables with the late modifier are not being initialized before they're being used. Why? Because the geolocation operation is not completing before the `build` method which uses `lat` and `long` is executing. Since those values are being used before the variables are initialized, you get the error. Possible solutions: have a flag to determine when the values are initialized, give them a default location so display (they don't need to be late, then).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use late and give value for all parametre

Answer (score 0):

The `getCurrentLocation` is an async function, and this async function in the `init` function may set your `lat` `long` variable after the engine renders the UI. In your build function, you use the `lat` and `long` so it raises an error that the `lat`, `long` haven't initialized yet. You should change from `late` to var for the `lat` and `long`, then the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use `FutureBuilder` and pass `getCurrentLocation` method as future parameter like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';

class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _YourWidgetState createState() => _YourWidgetState();
}

class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  Future<Position>? _locationFuture;
  late String lat;
  late String long;
  late Coordinates coordinates;

  Future<Position> getCurrentLocation() async {
    // Your existing implementation of getCurrentLocation() here
    // ...
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _locationFuture = getCurrentLocation();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Your App")),
      body: FutureBuilder<Position>(
        future: _locationFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text("Error: ${snapshot.error}"));
          } else {
            final position = snapshot.data!;
            lat = "${position.latitude}";
            long = "${position.longitude}";

            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text("Latitude: $lat"),
                  Text("Longitude: $long"),
                  // You can now use 'coordinates.latitude' here without errors
                  // ...
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```